# error while reading csv file using d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am new to d3.js any help is much appreciated 
csv file is

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

code is

```
d3.csv("../test/car.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    year: new Date(+d.Year, 0, 1), // convert "Year" column to Date
    make: d.Make,
    model: d.Model,
    length: +d.Length // convert "Length" column to number
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
});
```

expected result is

```
[
  {"Year": "1997", "Make": "Ford", "Model": "E350", "Length": "2.34"},
  {"Year": "2000", "Make": "Mercury", "Model": "Cougar", "Length": "2.38"}
]
```

but i am getting the following error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

also shows that the length as 86 but i have only 2 entries in the csv file not sure what is happening

Comment: Do you have `<!doctype html>` and `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your script? https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1195#issuecomment-16262373 And which `length` is 86?

Comment: You actually don't need to create a javascript Data and then parse it. You can actually just parse like normal numbers and you'll get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that musically_ut comment will solve your primary issue. However you also don't iterate on your data.

---

The data in `d` is an array with every entry being a row.

Hence, if you did:

```
d3.csv("../test/car.csv", function(d) {
  return d;
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
});
```

I guess that you would have the desired result.

If you want to go through your data you can do the following:

```
d3.csv("../test/car.csv", function(d) {
  d.forEach(function(data,index){
    // do something with row of index `index` with its data `data`
  })
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
});
```